# Spark ec2 web services start up error

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I am starting spark cluster in amazon EC2. In web UI I could see 2 instances(1 master and 1 slave) running and I am able to ssh to those instances. I opened up port 7077 inbound. When I try to launch the spark shell using the below command, I am getting an error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
spark-shell --master spark://ec2-54-173-210-192.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077
```

Logs:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to ec2-54-173-210-192.compute-1.amazonaws.com/54.173.210.192:7077
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:183)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: ec2-54-173-210-192.compute-1.amazonaws.com/54.173.210.192:7077
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
... 1 more
```

Comment: I would recommend removing public IPs from your post. Are you sure you've opened the ports properly? To which IP does the Spark master bound itself? Internal (private) or external (public)?

Answer (score 1):

Not really solving the problem but just a suggestion: If you want a Spark cluster on Amazon, try [Spark on Amazon EMR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark.html) before EC2. EMR lets you launch a managed cluster of any size to which Spark can be added as a preinstalled application. No need to configure hosts/ports yourself.